# How do I import jboolexpr-src-1.2.jar?

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I use the jar jboolexpr-src-1.2.jar in my java application?

http://jboolexpr.sourceforge.net/index.htm

I'm a rookie, so if the javadoc is telling me what I need I can't figure it out.

I have the jar included in my Eclipse build path, but I can't figure out what to import.  (Not the class to import, the "fully qualified" import string.)

I managed to get opencsv to work, but they told me the import "string" was au.com.bytecode.opencsv.*.

Comment: Thank you Peter, my problem was trying to work with the src version.  I did mention I was a rookie ... !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In such situations (when you have an unfamiliar library to use), you usually check its JavaDoc first. So check here the JavaDoc of this library.
http://jboolexpr.sourceforge.net/api/public/index.html
You know what task you want to solve. So then you import the classes which you need from that library in order to solve that task.
It also makes sense to play a few tests until you get familiar with the library.

2) You mention importing `jboolexpr-src-1.2.jar`. This jar contains the sources of this library, not its compiled binaries/classes. You need the binaries/classes. So get the jar which has no src in its name. It is called `jboolexpr-1.2.jar` in this case. See here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jboolexpr/files/jboolexpr/1.2/

Answer (score 1):

Even though the answer is already selected, I figured I'd add a bit more detailed information here for you, which should help with future issues regarding `.jar` files.

You can view what any `.jar` (Java ARchive) file contains with an archive viewer/extractor, such as WinRAR or 7-Zip.

Alternatively, you can also always run this command in the command-line/terminal to tell you the contents:

`jar tvf jar-file`

Options:
`t` list table of contents for file
`v` generate verbose output on standard output
`f` specify archive file name

Since the directory structure is really just based on the package names, you can easily look inside the archive and find the import path to the class files you need.

In the case of `jboolexpr-src-1.2.jar`, this is really just the source, but it does contains the `.jar` file you need: `jboolexpr-1.2.jar`, which you can extract and import into your project.

If you look inside `jboolexpr-1.2.jar`, you will see that the class files are all under the `jboolexpr` directory (package):

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
jboolexpr/
jboolexpr/demo/
jboolexpr/Boolean.class
jboolexpr/BooleanAndOperation.class
jboolexpr/BooleanExpression.class
jboolexpr/BooleanExpressionLR.class
jboolexpr/BooleanExpressionRL.class
jboolexpr/BooleanNotOperation.class
jboolexpr/BooleanOrOperation.class
jboolexpr/BooleanUtil.class
jboolexpr/IBoolean.class
jboolexpr/MalformedBooleanException.class
jboolexpr/demo/BooleanExpresionDemo$1.class
jboolexpr/demo/BooleanExpresionDemo.class
```

So, you can simply import everything with `import jboolexpr.*;` or import the specific class file you need.

As peter.petrov said, it's usually best to take a look at the [JavaDoc/Source Documentation](http://jboolexpr.sourceforge.net/api/public/index.html) first to see what packages the source contains and how to use it. And as Narendra Pathai mentioned, there is usually an auto-import option in most modern IDEs (Eclipse included) that you can take advantage of as long as you have imported the `.jar` into your project first.

Under Eclipse, you can find the shortcut for this and other keyboard shortcuts under `Window > Preferences > General > Keys`. If you search for "imports", you will find two:

**Add Import** (`Ctrl + Shift + M`): Create import statement on selection
**Organize Imports** (`Ctrl + Shift + O`): Evaluate all required imports and replace the current imports

Also in Eclipse, when you are utilizing a class that is not imported yet, you can hover your cursor over the red underlined class you want to import and the option to import it will appear.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the [example](http://jboolexpr.sourceforge.net/example.htm) in the link you pointed to shows, You will have to import `jboolexpr.BooleanExpression` for it.

Or if you are using eclipse just do `BooleanExpression boolExpr = BooleanExpression.readLeftToRight(strBoolExpr);` and press `Ctrl + Shift + O` for organizing imports and Eclipse will find appropriate import or will ask if there are two classes with same name.